# Picasso not working with drawable resource in Android

Tags: android, picasso

```
ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.img);
int resId = R.drawable.coffee;
Picasso.get().load(resId).into(img);
```

Why it is not working. but the following worked fine:

```
ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.img);
String path= "https://images.pexels.com/photos/434213/pexels-photo-434213.jpeg";
Picasso.get().load(path).into(img);
```

Comment: not working? what do you mean sir?

Comment: Make sure your drawable coffee is valid. Share the Log

Comment: `Picasso.with(<Object of context class>).load(path).into(img);`

Comment: Just curious. Why do you even need Picasso to load a drawable into an image view? Doesn't setDrawable() suffice?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use following code (`this` is `context`):

```
Picasso.with(this)
.load(R.drawable.coffee)
.into(img);
```

You can also ged rid of Picasso:

```
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.coffee);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was adding image to drawable directly by copy and paste.
But you need to add it properly using minmap.
The your drawable resource will work in Picass without any issue.